# Frequently selecting different combo box items crashing winrt phone application

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, combobox, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

My application was crashing so I made this sample app and this is also crashing.

**xaml:**

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Vertical" >
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock x:Uid="EmirateTextBlock" />
        </StackPanel>
        <ComboBox PickerFlyoutBase.Title=" " Name="EmirateComboBox" x:Uid="EmirateComboBox" PlaceholderText="" DisplayMemberPath="vcPlateSource" />

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock x:Uid="CategoryTextBlock" />
        </StackPanel>
        <ComboBox PickerFlyoutBase.Title=" " Name="CategoryComboBox" x:Uid="CategoryComboBox" PlaceholderText="" DisplayMemberPath="vcPlateCateg"  />

    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
</Page>
```

**.cs file:**

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        PopulateComboBox();
        this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked when this page is about to be displayed in a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">Event data that describes how this page was reached.
    /// This parameter is typically used to configure the page.</param>
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: Prepare page for display here.

        // TODO: If your application contains multiple pages, ensure that you are
        // handling the hardware Back button by registering for the
        // Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed event.
        // If you are using the NavigationHelper provided by some templates,
        // this event is handled for you.
    }

    public class stbPlateSource
    {
        public int tiPlateSourceId { get; set; }
        public string cCountryCode { get; set; }
        public string vcPlateSourceDesc { get; set; }
        public string vcPlateSource
        {
            get
            {
                if (!IsEnglish)
                {
                    return nvcPlateSourceArbDesc;
                }
                else
                {
                    return vcPlateSourceDesc;
                }
            }
        }
        public static bool IsEnglish { get; set; }
        public string nvcPlateSourceArbDesc { get; set; }
        public int tiDisplayOrder { get; set; }

    }
    public class stbPlateCateg
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int tiPlateCategId { get; set; }
        public int tiPlateSourceId { get; set; }
        public string vcPlateCategDesc { get; set; }
        public string nvcPlateCategArbDesc { get; set; }
        public static bool IsEnglish { get; set; }
        public string vcPlateCateg
        {
            get
            {
                if (!IsEnglish)
                {
                    return this.nvcPlateCategArbDesc;
                }
                else
                {
                    return this.vcPlateCategDesc;
                }
            }
        }

        public stbPlateCateg() { }
    }

    private void PopulateComboBox()
    {
        // Step1
        List<stbPlateSource> Emirates = new List<stbPlateSource>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 250; i++)
        {
            Emirates.Add(new stbPlateSource() {
                 cCountryCode = "05" + i,
                 tiDisplayOrder = i+1,
                 tiPlateSourceId = 101 + i,
                 vcPlateSourceDesc = "asd" + i,
                 nvcPlateSourceArbDesc = "dsa" + i
            });
        }
        stbPlateSource.IsEnglish = true;
        EmirateComboBox.ItemsSource = Emirates;

        List<stbPlateCateg> PlateCategory = new List<stbPlateCateg>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 250; i++)
        {
            PlateCategory.Add(new stbPlateCateg()
            {
                Id = 201 + i,
                tiPlateCategId = i + 1,
                tiPlateSourceId = 101 + i,
                vcPlateCategDesc = "asd" + i,
                nvcPlateCategArbDesc = "dsa" + i
            });
        }
        stbPlateCateg.IsEnglish = true;
        CategoryComboBox.ItemsSource = PlateCategory.OrderBy(x => x.tiPlateCategId);


        EmirateComboBox.SelectedIndex = 1;
        CategoryComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }


}
```

When I frequently changes combo box selected items the application crashing, although my original application crashes very frequently but this crash after a long time.

And when it crashes while I was debugging, it just crashes and doesn't through any exception. I don't know how can I handle this.

I don't have any prove but this I think this is some kind of memory exception.

Answer (score 0):

These combo boxes doesn't work well, at the end I have to make a button with hidden. listbox bellow it to handle this.

Like this

```
<Button Name="EmirateComboButton"  Click="EComboButton_Click" Style="{StaticResource ListboxButton}" />
<ListBox Name="EComboListBox" x:Uid="EComboListBox" Visibility="Collapsed" Tapped="EComboListBox_Tapped" SelectionChanged="EComboListBox_SelectionChanged" 
    Style="{StaticResource ListboxCombo}" DisplayMemberPath="vcPSource" ItemsSource="{Binding EBind}"
    >
</ListBox>
```

you have to be careful for handling many things like detecting tap to hide listbox, animation, etc